# where did the memory go?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, sizeof

```
class Node
{
//some member variables.
};
std::cout<<"size of the class is "<<sizeof(Node)<<"\n";
int pm1 =peakmemory();
std::cout<<"Peak memory before loop is "<< pm1<<"\n";
for(i=0; i< nNode; ++i)
{
  Node * p = new Node;
}
int pm2 =peakmemory();
std::cout<<"Peak memory after loop is "<< pm2<<"\n";
```

I thought `pm2-pm1` approximates `nNode * sizeof(Node)`. But it turns out `pm2-pm1` is much larger than `nNode *sizeof(Node)`. Where did the memory go? I suspect `sizeof(Node)` does not reflect the correct memory usage.

I have tested on both Windows and linux. Final conclusion is `Node * p = new Node;` will allocate a memory larger than `sizeof(Node)` where `Node` is a class.

Comment: What is your actual output?

Comment: `new` allocates more memory than you request.  It has to store metadata inside the memory block for `delete` to use (allocation size, etc), as well as for the MemoryManager itself (mark the memory in use, etc). It also has to ensure the returned pointer is aligned properly, which may require rounding up the allocated size.

Comment: What is `peakmemory` and how is it implemented?

Comment: Consider that memory is often allocated to processes as pages when the process needs more.

Comment: What is `peakmemory()`?

Comment: Does it really matter?  What is it that you are trying to determine?

Comment: In some environments like Visual Studio in debug mode allocations may have guard bytes used for heap corruption detection.

Comment: I'd say that's "implementation defined". Whether or not an implementation allocates more memory than you need is not something you need to concern yourself with. Whether an implementation gives memory back to the OS when you free it is also not of your concern. The OS may also itself allocate memory sparsely (or not) but your program doesn't know (and shouldn't care).

Comment: The one thing you can be sure of though is that once your process exits, the kernel will reclaim *all* the memory it used - leaks or no leaks. You can't leak memory past process exit (ok, there are exceptions, like sysv shared memory and the like, but those are esoteric).

Comment: Your OS is clever. It doesn't keep unused memory around. It also sometimes caches memory. You cannot just look at what your program does in isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified what platform you're running on, here are a few possibilities:

1. Allocation size: Your C++ implementation may be allocating memory in units which are larger than `sizeof(Node)`, e.g. to limit the amount of book-keeping it does.
2. Alignment: The allocator may have a policy of returning addresses aligned to some minimum power of 2. Again, this may simplify its implementation somewhat.
3. Overhead: Some allocators, in addition to the memory *you* are using, have some padding with a fixed pattern to protect against memory corruption; or some meta-data used by the allocator.

That is not to say this *actually* happens. But it could; it certainly agrees with the language specification (AFAICT).

Comment: I have tested on both Windows and linux. Final conclusion is `Node * p = new Node;` will allocate a memory larger than `sizeof(Node)` where Node is a class.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all memory allocators (such as those on linux/win32) have an allocation header that proceeds the memory allocation (which includes info about the size of the allocation). On linux for example, you can look at the source for malloc, and that gives info about the stored header (and how to compute its size):

https://git.busybox.net/uClibc/tree/libc/stdlib/malloc/malloc.h#n106

As already mentioned in a comment, debug builds may also allocate additional bytes at either side of the allocation to guard against buffer overrun errors.